# What time format is this in?

Tags: time, format

I've just exracted some files from a .mat file and one of the datasets files is called "PTIME"

But I'm not 100% what the format is. Here is an example..

1282813001.74319 (not sure if the numbers passed the point are relevant)

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html

Answer (score 1):

The "Unix Epoch". The [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 (or 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). The posix time represents the number of milliseconds since this epoch.

`1282813001 = Thu Aug 26 2010 10:56:41 GMT+0200`

The fraction `74319` represents 10 microsecond units, so 0.74319 ms.

Comment: Technically, POSIX time represents the number of seconds since the Epoch, ignoring leap seconds.

Answer (score 0):

That would be Unix Epoch Time (or POSIX time). There are several converters online to test with. Here's the first that showed on my Google search:

[Epoch Converter - Unix Timestamp Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

The page also shows how to convert to and from the date in multiple languages.